# Группировка в SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, sql

Господа, подскажите, есть ли возможность, используя SimpleCursorAdapter стандартно в ListView, сделать группировку одинаковых значений в одно? И также, чтобы у данного значения появлялся индикатор, что значение включает в себя n количество элементов

Comment: нет такой стандартной возможности.

Comment: Понял, а какие могут быть альтернативы?

Comment: альтернатива - кастомный адаптер с нужным функционалом, возможно на основе `ExpandableListView` или поискать готовую реализацию на том же Androi Arsenal